# how to search in specific website using google

Tags: google-search

As all know that we can search in specific website by using:

```
keywords site:websitename.com

or

keywords site:65.45.34.4
```

Now how to search in website that use port 5050 like 65.45.34.4:5050?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Please provide a real example.